# Countable vs Recursively Enumerable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science

I've been reading that recursively enumerable sets are countable (enumerable in the general sense), but not vice a versa, when there is no function for the enumeration. Could you describe exactly how this can be? If there is a method for counting all the elements, how can there be no function to do so?

Comment: A function is not the same thing as an algorithm. There are some examples of such sets at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81537/are-there-any-countable-sets-that-are-not-computably-enumerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are uncountably many countable subsets of the natural numbers (since you can apply the [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) to the set of countable sequences), but only countably many recursively enumerable ones (since they correspond to finite algorithms, which you can enumerate).

There’s no contradiction there. That you see a contradiction may be related to your imprecise use of “method” and “function”. A set is countable if there is a bijection between it and the natural numbers. The existence of a bijection doesn’t imply the existence of a finite algorithm that specifies the bijection.

Comment: thanks, I claiming contradiction in my knowledge, not that there IS a contradiction